# Making a new specific object from a class generic

Tags: java, android, class, generics

Okay, so I've done some looking around and I think I might be going about this wrong. I've taken classes in college for C++ as electives and I like to tinker, but I'm still learning Java.

So I'm using a ListAdapter to put a list of different fragments that the user can pick from, then the fragment they chose sits where the ListAdapter was. It only takes arrays, no biggie.

```
/**
 * An array of POJOs used to hold the info about the fragments we'll be
 * swapping between This should be inserted into an array adapter of some
 * sort before being passed onto ListAdapter
 */
private static final FragmentDetails[] FRAGMENT_DETAILS = {
        new FragmentDetails(R.string.action_extraInfo,
                R.string.extraInfo_description,
                ExtraInfoFragment.class),
        new FragmentDetails(R.string.action_largeTach,
                R.string.largeTach_description, 
                LargeTachFragment.class),
                ...
            };
/**
 * @author PyleC1
 * 
 *         A POJO that holds a class object and its resource info
 */
public static class FragmentDetails {
    private final Class<? extends Fragment> fragmentClass;
    private int titleId;
    private int descriptionId;
/**
     * @param titleId
     *            The resource ID of the string for the title
     * @param descriptionId
     *            The resource ID of the string for the description
     * @param fragmentClass
     *            The fragment's class associated with this list position
     */
    FragmentDetails(int titleId, int descriptionId,
            Class<? extends Fragment> fragmentClass) {
            super();
        this.titleId = titleId;
        this.descriptionId = descriptionId;
        this.fragmentClass = fragmentClass;
    }

    ...
}
```

At any rate, I run this through a simple get/set class called CustomArrayAdapter and send it off to ListAdapter when the fragment is attached.

```
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);

    ListAdapter listAdapter = new CustomArrayAdapter(getActivity(),
        FRAGMENT_DETAILS);
    setListAdapter(listAdapter);
```

}

So far so good. The problem comes in when I try to program the onListItemClick listener. I can't seem to find a way to create a real object from the class info. I looked around and found the .getClass().newInstance() function was supposed to be roughly similar to new  so I tried this.

```
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    FragmentDetails details = (FragmentDetails) getListAdapter().getItem(position);

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = ...
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = ...

        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, 
                                details.fragmentClass.newInstance());
}
```

Doing that throws an Illegal Access Exception in the compiler. I know something similar was acceptable in C++. A class pointer maybe? But that might be the complete wrong way in Java. Not typesafe perhaps?

My only other thought is to remove the

```
Class<? extends Fragment> fragmentClass
```

generic from the array and just use a switch statement (from the title id perhaps) to hard code the fragment transactions, although that seems a bit inelegant. It works fine if you want to launch new activites, you can just pass the generic class to the intent like this:

```
Class<? extends Foo> bar = someFooClass.getClass();
new Intent(this, bar);
```

But fragments don't accept this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance%28%29):

```
IllegalAccessException - if the class or its nullary constructor is not accessible.
```

So if you want to instantiate your fragment using reflection, all possible classes `<? extends Fragment>` need to provide a `public` no-arguments constructor.

Comment: Sweet thanks. I couldn't seem to find the answer and I knew it was something simple. I also had to add in a try catch block and typecast the object. `Object foo; try { foo = details.fragmentClass.newInstance(); } catch ...` 

Then I could call: `fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, (Fragment)foo);` With no problems

Comment: Since `newInstance()` is generic, it should be possible to assign `details.fragmentClass.newInstance();` directly to a variable of type `Fragment` if your `fragmentClass` is still parameterized with `<? extends Fragment>`.

Comment: Just around to checking this, and that works like you said. My real job got in the way for awhile. lol. Thanks for all the help. I accepted your answer, hope I don't need to do anything else. I bookmarked that oracle page. The official java docs should be a great resource. Wish I had known about them sooner. The documentation in eclipse is abysmal and assumes you know java very well and the android docs are no better.